# Java ZipEntry and Zipoutputstream directory

Tags: java, zip

I have this little piece of code

```
   public void doBuild() throws IOException {
    ZipEntry sourceEntry=new ZipEntry(sourcePath);
    ZipEntry assetEntry=new ZipEntry(assetPath);
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("output/"+workOn.getName().replaceAll(".bld"," ")+buildNR+".zip"));
     out.putNextEntry(sourceEntry);
    out.putNextEntry(assetEntry);
    out.close();
    System.err.println("Build success!");
    increaseBuild();

}
```

So, if I run it it runs trough it fine, creates the .zip and all, but the zip file is empty. sourceEntry and assetEntry are both directories. How could I get those directories to my .zip easily?

For those interested this is a MC mod build system and can be found at https://bitbucket.org/makerimages/makerbuild-system **NOTE: the code above is not commited or pushed to there yet!!!!!!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. The parameter useFullFileNames specifies
whether you want to preserve the full names of the paths to the 
files which you're about to zip.

So if you have two files
**/dir1/dir2/a.txt**
and
**/dir1/b.txt**
the useFullFileNames specifies if you want to finally see in 
the zip file those original paths to the two files or just
the two files with no paths like this
**a.txt**
and
**b.txt**
in the root of the zip file which you create.

Note that in my example, the files which are zipped 
are actually read and then written to **out**.
I think you're missing that part.

```
    public static boolean createZip(String fNameZip, boolean useFullFileNames, String... fNames) throws Exception {
        try {
            int cntBufferSize = 256 * 1024;
            BufferedInputStream origin = null;
            FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(fNameZip);
            ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(dest));
            byte bBuffer[] = new byte[cntBufferSize];
            File ftmp = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < fNames.length; i++) {
                if (fNames[i] != null) {
                    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(fNames[i]);
                    origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, cntBufferSize);
                    ftmp = new File(fNames[i]);
                    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(useFullFileNames ? fNames[i] : ftmp.getName());
                    out.putNextEntry(entry);
                    int count;
                    while ((count = origin.read(bBuffer, 0, cntBufferSize)) != -1) {
                        out.write(bBuffer, 0, count);
                    }
                    origin.close();
                }
            }
            out.close();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: List the file names in the two directories, unite the two lists, then pass this united list as the value for the parameter fNames using the method/function I provided. This should work.

Comment: I used http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Makingazipfileofdirectoryincludingitssubdirectoriesrecursively.htm and it eorked.. explorer show the zip file empty, but 7zip does show contents